# Adding typename causes program to fail compilation

Tags: c++, templates

So I have this code:

```
#include "type_traits"

struct A{
    int member;
};

struct B{
    typedef A object;
    typedef int member;
};

typedef std::integral_constant<B::member, B::object::*, &A::member> type;
```

But if I change the final line to:

```
typedef std::integral_constant<typename B::member, typename B::object::*, &A::member> type;
```

The program will not compile....

Why does adding the `typename` specifier cause the program to not compile?  This is especially surprising to me because I thought I needed it in this case.

Note:
Using gcc 5.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add `typename` everywhere you want to specify a type. You can only, and require to add `typename` when you use a dependent type name.

A dependent name is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() { (void)T::member(); }
```

Is `T::member` a type, or a member function named `member`? The compiler will assume it's not a type by default. If it is a type, you must specify `typename` to disambiguate.

```
template<typename T>
void foo() { (void)typename T::member(); }
```

Now the compiler is told to assume that `T::member` is indeed a type.

However, the C++ syntax only allow it in cases that the nature of `T::member` cannot be known. So when dealing with know types, like your code, the compiler already know that these members are types. There's nothing to desambiguate.

If you were to change you typedef by a template alias, it would require `typename` as you wrote:

```
template<typename C, typename D> //          v----- Type of pointer to member?
using type = std::integral_constant<typename D::member D::object::*, &C::member>;
//        Here, D::object::* don't need typename,  ----^
//        since only types are allowed here
```